# Is there a way to test verification emails using Karate?

Tags: karate

The problem I have is that I need to test if user verification is working. We generate a verification token, and an email is sent to the user. Whenever the user clicks on it, it checks if the verification token has expired. I've tried mocking this, but it just won't work. We have an endpoint to verify a user, but we still need the verification token, which is not available on any endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this article may help you: https://www.testingexcellence.com/automated-api-testing-emails-karate/

To summarize:

- use the API at http://qamail.ala.se/ to create a test mailbox
- initiate the flow that sends the e-mail
- use the API to "read" the e-mail and grab the token

EDIT: looks like the link is dead. but you should be able to find similar offerings on the internet. since the source-code seems to be available, it may make sense for you to host this e-mail server somewhere so that it can receive e-mail from whichever system is the sender

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was pretty helpful. Also I found about putsbox.com, which is really easy to use for this purpose.

Comment: @MiguelFlores great !since you are new to SO may I request you to mark this answer as "accepted"